# where do I find the connection string in azure data studio since I am using mac and to scaffold I am going to need it

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, azure, scaffolding

I am having trouble finding the structure(syntax) of the connection string of azure data studio with visual studio so I can scaffold data into it

I tried many ways but I am not really sure which one is the right one, since it's my first time using visual studio and db on mac

Comment: Have you looked in www.connectionstrings.com?

Comment: I just checked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Stringeater for your comment.

If you want to connect Azure SQL database in visual studio you can find `Connection strings` option in SQL database tab

[image]

By using above required connection strings you are able connect database in visual studio. Otherwise as @Stringeater said check [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for SQL server connection strings.

Sample Connection String:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=<serverName>;Database=<datanaseName>;UID=<userName>;PWD=<password>;
```